# How does fread know where it last stopped?

Tags: c, fread

Fread apparently knows the place where it last stopped, by that I mean this:

```
while(fread(buffer, 1, 1, file))
{
    …
}
```

This loop would continue the next time where it stopped the last time. I assume it just moves the *file* pointer forward, but could someone explain if it’s exactly like that?

Comment: You will get your answer hear [fread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) copied from link `The file position indicator for the stream is advanced by the number of characters read.`

Comment: The useless `!` means the loop won't continue if it read anything, but will attempt to if it doesn't. You should compare `fread` with the specific number of items requested.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry I made a mistake, I have removed it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `fread` reads from a stream, which is not necessarily a file. Streams can also be linked to consoles/terminals. Some streams are seekable and have a file position indicator, some do not. Streams which are linked to actual files usually do have a file position indicator.

The function `fread` itself does not advance any file position indicator (it does not call [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)). It just reads from the stream.

If a stream has a file position indicator, then the [runtime library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library) will advance the file position indicator, whenever a read takes place on the stream. It does this for all reads on the stream, not just for `fread`.

Comment: In particular, C 2018 7.21.1 2 says the `FILE` type “is an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a stream, including its file position indicator,…” and 7.21.3 1 says “… If a file can support positioning requests (such as a disk file, as opposed to a terminal), then a *file position indicator* associated with the stream… The file position indicator is maintained by subsequent reads, writes, and positioning requests, to facilitate an orderly progression through the file.”